# Отправка сообщений по приглашению бота discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Как сделать так, чтобы когда бот присоединяется к новому серверу, он отправлял какое-то сообщение? Никак не могу разобраться в discord.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    await guild.text_channels[0].send(join_message)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете использовать системный канал сервера [документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=system_channel#discord.Guild.system_channel):

Пример:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    if guild.system_channel is not None: # если у сервера есть системный канал то мы отправляем туда сообщение
        guild.system_channel.send('Hello guild') # если нету то владельцу сервера
    elif guild.system_channel is None:
        user = client.get_user(guild.owner.id)
        user.send('Bot join to your server')
```